# How to pass variables to render_to_string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, render-to-string

Trying to do the following

```
@message = render_to_string ( :sender => sender, :template => "template" )
```

But when accessing @sender in template it turns out to be nil:NilClass. Double checked if I pass the right variable and it's totally fine. Maybe there are other way to pass variables to render_to_string?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It might be the syntax you're using. Try using the `:locals` argument:

```
@m = render_to_string :template => "template", :locals => {:sender => sender}
```

Then you just need to access `sender` (without an `@`) as a local variable inside the template.

Comment: Just noticed you were trying to access sender as `@sender` in your view. Not sure about your original code, but if you use the locals syntax, it will be a local variable (not an instance variable) and will be accessed without the `@`

Comment: Your solution actually work. You can pass locals as you said and access them as local variables, not instance variables.

Comment: I've been trying to use `render_to_string` from model. In order to use with as instance variable, I had to do `ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(:template => "template", :locals => {:@sender => sender})`

Answer (score 22):

Here's [Jason Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/536890/jason-kim)'s solution he wrote in a comment which worked for me:

```
ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string(
  "user_mailer/welcome_email.html.erb", locals: { :@user => user}
)
```

Please mind the `:@user => value` bit.

---

In Rails 5 (atm in beta):

```
ApplicationController.render(
  file: 'path',
  assigns: { foo: 'bar' }
)
```

[More here](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/new-feature-in-rails-5-render-views-outside-of-actions)

Comment: Doesn't work in the latest 4-2-stable https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4c46a15e0a7815ca9e4cd7c7fda042eb8c1b7724#commitcomment-41917002

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
ac = ActionController::Base.new()  
ac.render_to_string(:partial => 'path to your partial',:locals => {:varable => your variables})
```

Answer (score 2):

In rails 4.0.2 this worked:

```
render_to_string(partial: 'path/to/partial', locals: { argument: 'value'}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to render a different format of partial in render_to_string. The thing which really worked for me was:

> render_to_string(:partial => 'partial_file.html', :locals => {:variable => variable}, :format => :html)

where the name of the file was `_partial_file.html.erb`.