# Rendering Rails entity as file

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, rendering

I've got a problem which seems to be quite hard to solve in Rails.

Consider having an entity `Book` which contains many `Pages`, and consider this `Pages` having an attribute `text` which contains (as strange as it may sound) text. More precisely, it is HTML code, and users are usually shown this text when accessing `pages/some_page_id/show`. Instead, users are shown an "index" of all the pages of a book when they go to `books/some_book_id/show`.

Now consider I want to let users "download" a book. The book will be downloaded as a zip containing an HTML file for each of its pages.

I'm quite fine with most passages, except with one: managing to render a `Page`, on a file, when a `BooksController` method is called.

What I've actually come up with is this line, in `BooksController/show`:

```
def show
  if params[:download]
   @book.pages.each do |p|
     content = render_to_string(:controller => "pages", :action => "show", :page_id => p.id)
     File.open(file_name_from_book_name_and_page_number) do |f|
      f.write(content)
     end
   end
 end
```

This results in a file for each page... But it's content is the content of the HTML the user would see if calling `BooksController/show` without any `params[:download]`! That is, what is actually called is not the `PagesController/show` action with a page id as argument...

How could I achieve that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14350708/how-to-render-erb-template-to-string-inside-action

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that params hash is passed to render_to_string method.

Try this answer [How to pass variables to render_to_string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714198/how-to-pass-variables-to-render-to-string)