# How to pass a variable to render_to_string from a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to pass a variable to render_to_string from a model.

This question is similar to [How to pass variable to render_to_string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714198/how-to-pass-variables-to-render-to-string)

I've read the answers in that question. I'm trying to use the `locals`. But, I still can't get it to work.

This is my model code:

```
pdf2 = CostprojectsController.new.render_to_string pdf: "Captital Projects.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8", locals: {:@costproject => @costproject}
```

But, in the view `costprojects/viewproject`, `@costproject` is nil and `costproject` is nil

I've tried:

```
locals: {costproject: @costproject}
locals: {@costproject: @costproject}
locals: {:costproject => @costproject}
```

Thanks for the help!!

UPDATE1 (I appreciate the help)

I tried this (adding parens):

```
pdf2 = CostprojectsController.new.render_to_string(pdf: "Captital Projects.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8", locals: {costproject: @costproject})
```

I added this line just before `pdf2`

```
raise @costproject.inspect
```

And I got:

```
#<Costproject id: 9, project_name: ...
```

In the view, should the passed var be `@costproject`

Comment: Try using parenthesis: `CostprojectsController.new.render_to_string(pdf: "Captital Projects.pdf", template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8", locals: { costproject: @costproject })`

Comment: the correct call would be

pdf2 = CostprojectsController.new.render_to_string(template: "costprojects/viewproject", encoding: "UTF-8", locals: {costproject: @costproject})

- is the @costproject var setted correctly when calling render_to_string?
- could you try the call with 'layout: nil' option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
controller = CostprojectsController.new
controller.instance_variable_set(:"@costproject", @costproject)  
pdf2 = controller.render_to_string(pdf: "Captital Projects.pdf", 
                                   template: "costprojects/viewproject", 
                                   encoding: "UTF-8")
```

The call to `instance_variable_set` should simulate setting `@costproject` in the body of a `before_filter` or controller action. This should make it available inside the call to `render_to_string`

Comment: @Reddirt if you mean you have another variable called `@useremail` then make another call to `instance_variable_set` but swap `costproject` for `useremail`.